# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] when using sphinx and autodoc

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I am trying to use sphinx to run an autodoc. My project structure like this:

[image]

Where the python files are reading from `input/input.xlsx`.
My `conf.py` looks like:

```
import os 
import sys 
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../../'))

extensions = ['sphinx.ext.autodoc']
```

I run the `./docs/sphinx-apidoc -o ./source ../` where it creates a:

> module.rst

and:

> My_Project.rst

inside the `./docs/source`.

My issue is that when I build the `make html`, it gives me errors like:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './input'

However, as I have set in `conf.py`, it should logically go two levels high and one level down to `/input` folder.

> ../../input

Appreciate any ideas.

Comment: @bad_coder. Yes, I did that too. But that totally screwed the code and caused new errors since the other files are located in `../../` relative path. Finally I figured out something that worked for me. But before I need to clarify something, in one of files in `../../` the code is reading the excel file from this path `./input/input.xlsx`. Bellow code resolved my issue: 

```directory_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
new_path = os.path.join(directory_path, "input.xlsx")```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I figured out something that worked for me. Beforehand, I need to clarify something: in one of python files located in `../../` from my `source` directory, the code is reading an excel file from this path `./input/input.xlsx`. I figured out that defining a hard coded path is the source of this issue. So I fixed it with following code:

```
directory_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) 
new_path = os.path.join(directory_path, "input.xlsx")
```